# Rails - Get 3 ID's in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

I have a `group#view` page, that is accessed by a `Person`. In this page, the `Person` can see the members of the `group` via methods I developed. The problem is that I need to create the model `Honors` using the Id from the `group`, the id from the `person` accessing the page, and the id from a `member` of this `group`.

In my `Honors` controller I have:

```
def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), 
  :person => Person.find(current_person), :honored => Person.find(current_person))
 if @honor.save
 ...
end
```

The problem is in this `:honored => Person.find(current_person)`, that is not getting the right ID and I don`t know how to get it.

In my view:

```
 <% @asked_groupmembership.each do |agm| %>
 <% form_for(:honor, :url => honors_path(:group_id => @group.id, :person => current_person.id,:honor => agm.member.id)) do |f| %>
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does current_person come from?

Comment: This is working it comes from the session control. Whoever acess the page will be the `current_person`. I know that in `:honored => Person.find(current_person)`, `current_person` should not be there, but I just don't know what to put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need 3 components to properly create an honor record, you need to pass them from the form.  You seem to be doing that part correctly.

```
:group_id => @group.id
:person => current_person.id
:honor => agm.member.id
```

To create the record, access the passed variables.

```
Honor.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]),
             :person => Person.find(params[:person]),
             :honored => Person.find(params[:honor]))
```

Understanding the above isn't the most efficient, but used for demonstrative purposes.  You'd likely want to avoid redundant database hits, e.g. `:person => current_person` rather than another query

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try this out right away. I tried something else and opened a new question, trying to pass those Ids throgh a `new form`. Could you please take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112340/rails-need-help-in-this-form