# Passing IDs through a new Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

This question is about a different approach I'm trying to the one asked here:

[Passing IDs through a new Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112340/rails-need-help-in-this-form)

I have a `group#view page`, that is accessed by a `Person`. In this page, the `Person` can see the members of the group via methods I developed. The problem is that I need to create the model `Honors` using the Id from the `group`, the id from the `person` accessing the page, and the id from a `member` of this `group`.

In my Honors controller I have:

```
def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @asked_groupmembership = @person.owned_group_memberships.find_all_by_status(true,:include => [:group, :member])
  @asked_groupmembership.each do |agm|
  @honor = Honor.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]), 
  :person => Person.find(current_person), :honored => Person.find(agm.member.id))
  end
 if @honor.save
 ...
end
```

In my view I have a link that directs the `person` to the form in order to create a new honor:

```
<% @asked_groupmembership.each do |agm| %>
  <%= link_to "Create Honor", new_honor_path(:group_id => @group.id, :person => current_person.id,
  :honored => agm.member.id) %>
```

But in my forms I can't get the ids and stuff

```
<% form_for(:honor, :url => honors_path(:group_id, :person,
 :honored)) do |f| %>
```

The error I get is that I can't find Group without an Id.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**##Edited2##**

Changed my `crontroller`

```
def new
  #@person = Person.find(params[:person])
  #@honored = Person.find(params[:honored])
  #@group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @honor = Honor.new
end


def create
  @person = Person.find(current_person)
  @honor = Honor.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]),
           :person => Person.find(params[:person]),
           :honored => Person.find(params[:honored]))
 if @honor.save
 ...
end
```

Comment: your new method isn't going to work.  Going into the creation process, you don't know the answers to those questions.  e.g. group, honored.  The new method initialzes the form to ask the questions, the form answers the questions, the create method records the answers.

Comment: Please try to keep your questions different enough that people don't think you're re-asking the same question.

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems like you are missing a controller method.  Along with every form that creates a new object there are typically two controller methods

new

- Gathers up any data that the form needs to render itself
- Renders the form

create

- Collects the data from the form
- Creates the new object

It looks to me like you are missing the new method. In the new method you would gather up all the hidden data that the form needs (e.g. the information that the user is not going to type in directly, like the @person info).  Then, I would put this information in your form using hidden form parameters (rather then trying to put it in the form URL).

Comment: I have a `new` but I think I understood what you mean. I will edit my question and put there what I did and you see if is right ok? Also, can you tell me if my form is correct? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Objective**: From the group#view, loop through and create and "Add Honor" link for each member of the group, while keeping track of the specific member being honored, group in which said member is honored, and the person who is honoring.

The following accomplishes that objective.

**Route:**

```
match "honors/:group/:person/:honored" => "honors#create", :as=>"my_custom_new_honor"
```

**Group view:**

```
<% @asked_groupmembership.each do |agm| %>
  <%= link_to "Create Honor", my_custom_new_honor_path(:group=> @group.id, :person => current_person.id,:honored => agm.member.id) %>
```

**Honor Controller, Create Method**

```
@honor = Honor.create(:group => Group.find(params[:group_id]),
                      :person => Person.find(params[:person]),
                      :honored => Person.find(params[:honored]))
```

In this scenario you do not need the honor#new method, you're going directly to the create method.  This assumes all the relationships are established correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Doing option 1 I can't get `agm` since the form is on other page (`#new`). Basically, I have a link in the `group#page` that when you click directs you to the page with the form.

Comment: I think for what you're trying to do, Option 2, linking is better anyway.  You can remove the @honor variable and it works still.

Comment: I will try! But, looking to my routes here, when I click the button the directed route is `/honor`. Is this wrong?

Comment: You can run `rake routes` to determine your routes.  If you're using the form, the default routing should work `resources :honors`

Comment: But as I said, how would be my match and the link, the same as you put?

Comment: I think this won't work for my situation. `Honor` belongs to group and person, but still isn't nested with them. So this way I can't get any `id`

Comment: Thanks for editing and helping me out all that time. My `honor` model have other attributes, how I will add them too with this method?

Comment: If you have other attributes, then you'd want to point to your route to the new method and use a form to fill out the necessary attributes.  That obviously changes the objective but the principles already presented remain.

Comment: Can you edit answer to show me this? I tried the actual one out and is giving  me the same error from the start: `Couldn't find Group without an ID`. All the things I have done since the beggining point to this error, on clicking the link or the submit button. Any clue?

Comment: Seems the problem is to get this `Group`ID. Doing your way I can't acess the form for example, says I dont have the `Group` Id.